# edit variable value in a batch file using another batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, edit, string-substitution

existing A.bat :

```
rem set variable pathVariable to appropriate value

set pathVariable=../Doc/English/MyDoc.htm

rem asd
```

from B.bat, I need to update the value of pathVariable with a path containing spaces, but after replacing spaces with %20 So after running B.bat, A.bat should look like :

```
rem set variable pathVariable to appropriate value 

set pathVariable=C:/Program%20Files/XXX%20YYY/MyDoc.htm 

rem asd
```

I tried to play with this and could write

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inputFile=A.bat
set outputFile=A_New.bat
set pathVar=../Doc/English/MyDoc.htm
set newPathVarSpace=C:/Program Files/XXX YYY/MyDoc.htm

set space=%%20
set newPathVarNoSpace=%newPathVarSpace: =!space!%
echo %newPathVarNoSpace%

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%A in ( '"type %inputFile%"') do (
SET line=%%A
rem SET modified=!string:%pathVar%=%newPathVarSpace%!
SET modifiedLine=!line:%pathVar%=%newPathVarNoSpace%!

echo !modifiedLine! >> %outputFile%
)
```

The script works but its eating all the blank lines which I want to preserve.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `|find /n /v """` - you are trying to find output that contains quotes?

Comment: What is not working? Nothing is echoed to the `%file%_new` ?

Comment: I was not able to post new script in the comment so I updated the original question itself, which I guess is not recommended. Sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below piece of code -

**A.BAT**

```
rem set variable pathVariable to appropriate value.
pathVariable=C:\Test
```

**B.BAT**

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "config=.\A.bat"
    set "path=C:\Batch projects\Batch tests\bin\Debug App"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "%config%"^&cd.^>"%config%"'
    ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims== " %%a in ("%%~l"
    ) do if /i "%%~a"=="pathVariable" (
        >>"%config%" echo(pathVariable=%path%
    ) else (
        >>"%config%" echo(%%l
    )

    type "%config%"

    endlocal
```

Now go to `A.BAT`, Open it with Notepad and check the pathVariable Value as below -

```
C:\Batch projects\Batch tests\bin\Debug App
```

Comment: I updated the original question and script I used. Its working but I am not able to handle the blank lines. Hope someone can help.